# Reference book on Riemann zeta function and random matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, random-matrices, riemann-zeta-function, textbook-recommendation

What is a reference book to understand the relation between the Riemann zeta function and random matrices?

Comment: Random Matrices - Madan Lal Mehta - Academic Press, Elsevier

Comment: If you are an undergraduate, you might look at An Invitation to Modern Number Theory by Miller and Takloo-Bighash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a substantial literature; for an introduction, you could start with the chapter by Keating and Snaith in the [Handbook of Random Matrix Theory](https://doi.org/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780198744191.013.24). For a more specialized overview, take a look at [Recent Perspectives in Random Matrix Theory and Number Theory](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511550492).

For a selection of research articles on this topic, see the list given by [Matthew Watkins](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/random.htm) (scroll to the bottom of the page).